# getting error TypeError at /login/ ChatroomMiddleware.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'receive' and 'send'

Tags: python, django, chat, channel

i am trying to create a middleware for my chatroom/consumer so that i can access current logged-in user object in my consumer.py,
but getting a error "getting error TypeError at /login/ ChatroomMiddleware._*call*_() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'receive' and 'send'"

### chatroom/consumer.py ( chatroom is app of my project)

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chatroom.views import get_user_exist

class GlobalChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    roomID = "global_room"
    sender = None
    message = ""

    async def connect(self):
        self.sender = self.scope["user"]
        print("USER ----> $", self.sender)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.roomID, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

        messages = await self.retrieve_room_messages()

        async for message in messages:
            sender_username = await database_sync_to_async(lambda: message.sender.username)()
            await self.send(
                text_data=json.dumps(
                    {
                        "type": "chat_message",
                        "message": message.content,
                        "sender": sender_username,
                    }
                )
            )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.roomID, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

        message_type = text_data_json.get("type")
        self.message = text_data_json.get("message")

        print("Message type", message_type)
        print("Message -> ", self.message)

        if message_type == "join_room":
            self.roomID = text_data_json.get("roomID")
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.roomID, self.channel_name)
            await self.send(
                text_data=json.dumps(
                    {"type": "info", "message": f"You have joined room {self.roomID}"}
                )
            )

        elif message_type == "chat_message":
            await self.save_chat_db()
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.roomID,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "message": self.message,
                    "sender": self.scope.get("user").username,
                },
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        sender = event["sender"]

        await self.send(
            text_data=json.dumps(
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "message": message,
                    "sender": sender,
                }
            )
        )

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self):
        user = get_user_exist()
        return user


    @database_sync_to_async
    def retrieve_room_messages(self):
        from chatroom.models import ChatMessage
        room_messages = ChatMessage.objects.filter(room=self.roomID)
        return room_messages

    @database_sync_to_async
    def save_chat_db(self):
        from chatroom.models import ChatMessage, RoomModel

        user = self.scope.get("user")

        if user:
            room = RoomModel.objects.get(roomID=self.roomID)

            message = ChatMessage.objects.create(
                sender=user,
                room=room,
                content=self.message,
            )
            message.save()
```

### my chatroom/middleware.py

```
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chatroom.views import get_user_exist

class ChatroomMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Retrieve user and attach it to the scope
        scope["user"] = await self.get_user(scope)
        
    
        await super().__call__(self, scope, receive, send)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self, scope):
        # Checking if the user is authenticated
        if scope.get("user") and scope["user"].is_authenticated:
            return get_user_exist()
        else:
            return None  # Or any other default behavior for unauthenticated users
```

### my project/asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# If DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is unset, default to the local settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "vibecheck.settings")

# Import websocket application here, so apps from django_application are loaded first
# This application object is used by any ASGI server configured to use this file.

from chatroom import routing  # noqa isort:skip
from chatroom.middleware import ChatroomMiddleware

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            ChatroomMiddleware(
                URLRouter(routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
            ),
        ),
    }
)
```

### below is my complete error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/khamseaffan/.local/share/virtualenvs/Wednesday-Fall2023-Team-1-Vewf75YA/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ChatroomMiddleware.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'receive' and 'send'
```

I tried changing middleware.py to the following, i.e. to by calling inner() bu that also did not work

```
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chatroom.views import get_user_exist

class ChatroomMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Retrieve user and attach it to the scope
        scope["user"] = await self.get_user(scope)
        
        # Call the inner application directly
        inner = self.inner(scope)
        return await inner(scope, receive, send)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self, scope):
        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if scope.get("user") and scope["user"].is_authenticated:
            return get_user_exist()
        else:
            return None  # Or any other default behavior for unauthenticated users
```

but this also did not work

Comment: As the error says, the `__call__` in the middleware should take only two parameters: `self` and `request`. So you can not use `receive` and `send`.